# How to call an API POST method only inside another API method in Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I was going through DRF, I want to call one API function which have GET and POST method inside another API function which also have get and post method. whether both get and post method will be called or Is it any way that I can achieve it. I was googling I didn't get any proper approach

If some one can demonstrate it would be helpful. what if I want to call POST method in another function?

views.py

## startshift

```
@api_view(['GET']) 
def UserStartShift(request):


    if request.method == 'POST':
     
               UserId = request.data.get('UserId')
               Ip = request.data.get('Ip')
               PortNumber = request.data.get('PortNumber')
               print("UserId-->", UserId)
               print("Ip-->", Ip)
               print('Portnumber-->', PortNumber)


               cursor = connection.cursor()
               cursor.execute('EXEC [dbo].[Usp_StartShift]  @UserId=%s, @IP=%s, @Port=%s', (UserId,  Ip, PortNumber,))
     
               return Response(True, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

## endshift

```
@api_view(['GET']) 
def UserStopShift(request, UserId):
    try:
        users = tblUserShiftDetails.objects.filter(UserId=UserId)
    except tblUserShiftDetails.DoesNotExist:
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)

    if request.method == 'GET':
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        cursor.execute('EXEC [dbo].[USP_StopShift] @UserId=%s',(UserId,))
       
        return Response(True)
```

#UserShiftDetailsView

```
 @api_view(['GET'])
def UserShiftDetailsView(request, userid):

    try:
        users = tblUserShiftDetails.objects.filter(UserId=userid)
    except tblUserShiftDetails.DoesNotExist:
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)

    if request.method == 'GET':

        if UserStartShift == True: 
            cursor = connection.cursor()
            cursor.execute('EXEC [dbo].[USP_GetCurrentShiftDetails] @UserId=%s',(userid,))
            result_set = cursor.fetchall()
         
            for row in result_set:
                row = row[0]
            return Response({"IsStarted":True,"EstimatedShifEnd":(row + datetime.timedelta(hours=9)).strftime('%d-%m-%Y %H:%M  %p'),"ReasonforAccess": "null"})
      
        elif UserStopShift == True :
            cursor = connection.cursor()
            cursor.execute('EXEC [dbo].[USP_GetCurrentShiftDetails] @UserId=%s',(userid,))
            result_set = cursor.fetchall()
          
            for row in result_set:
                row = row[0]
            return Response({"IsStarted":False,"EstimatedShifEnd":"null","ReasonforAccess": "null"})
```

Comment: Do you want to POST to a third party API, or to your API?

Comment: To the API function which I have created

Comment: Then you can just call it like you do in Python. You might find it helpful to extract the functionality from the view itself, so it would be easier to share the code.

Comment: I have added the code here where UserStartShift and UserStopShift these are the API function which I have created whenever the user starts the shift it will return the particular response and same applies for the stop shift as well. Here, I have conditional approach but its not succeded.Is there any approach that I could try it

Answer (score 2):

you can try this

Use python requests  https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/

```
import requests

class MyAPIOne(APIView):

    # headers

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

        # call another api for GET
        url = '/url-second-api-url'
        api_call = requests.get(url, headers={})
        print(api_call.json())

        # call another api for POST
        url = '/url-second-api-url'
        data = {} # post data
        api_call = requests.get(url, headers={}, data=data)
        print(api_call.json())

        return Response({})
```

Comment: Thanks, But rather then calling the url can't I call only the method name like in normal python we do

Comment: then you need to create a standalone method and then call that method into API

Comment: I have added the code here where UserStartShift and UserStopShift these are the API function which I have created whenever the user starts the shift it will return the particular response and same applies for the stop shift as well. Here, I have conditional approach but its not succeded.Is there any approach that I could try it

Comment: I have created using the function API views

Comment: you can't call a Django function without any URL. create a standalone function